# How to migrate from TensorFlow 1.x to TensorFlow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

```
class Model:
    def __init__(
        self,
        learning_rate,
        num_layers,
        size,
        size_layer,
        output_size,
        forget_bias = 0.1,
    ):
        def lstm_cell(size_layer):
            return tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size_layer, state_is_tuple = False)

        rnn_cells = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)],
            state_is_tuple = False,
        )
        self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, size))
        self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))
        drop = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
            rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias
        )
        self.hidden_layer = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
            tf.float32, (None, num_layers * 2 * size_layer)
        )
        self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            drop, self.X, initial_state = self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(self.outputs[-1], output_size)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y - self.logits))
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
            self.cost
        )
```

i want to convert this code above to relevant TensorFlow 2.x without eager execution, anyone can help?
I been trying to to change few things like: changing `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` to `tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell` and `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` to `tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells` also `tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn` to `tf.keras.layers.RNN`
how do i do this?

Comment: Have you checked this:https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: @sreagm is that automatic conversion from tensorflow 1 to 2?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate .Don't know whether code is converted or not.I think the backend is getting switched from v2 to v1.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow 1.x scripts will not work directly with TensorFlow 2.x but they need converting.

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --infile tensorflow_v1.py --outfile tensorflow_v2.py
```

If you have multiple files within a folder, you can use the below command.

```
tf_upgrade_v2  v1-code-folder  code-upgraded-folder
```